# QGIS slope percent calculation

Tags: raster, slope

I'm using QGIS and I'm trying to calculate slope < 20% from a file I have but when I use the raster calculation SLOPE < 20 the result is all black. What am I doing wrong? The data is already in percent.

Comment: Check the output raster properties and see what its range is. Check the min/max and scaling. Check the histogram to see if has 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

The result is all black because all values are 1. To get the true values you have to do (with the raster calculator nomenclature):

```
("SLOPE@1" < 20) * "SLOPE@1"
```

Comment: That will give you zero where the slope is greater than 20, and also zero where the slope is zero. I'm not sure that's what's wanted...