# How to understand/interpret slope unit values in QGIS 2.14?

Tags: raster, slope, qgis-2.14

When I create slope raster I get this result:

[image]

[image]

I can't understand the those values represent?

What are the units of those values?

I saw this question [QGIS slope percent calculation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171076/qgis-slope-percent-calculation) , but didn't find answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS slope result is in degrees. From [the official doc](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_raster_terrain.html) :

> Slope: Calculates slope angle for each cell in degrees (based on first
>   order derivative estimation).